# I accidentally delete API keys that automatically created by Google Firebase, what should I do?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

10 minutes ago, I just delete 3 keys that automatically created by Firebase/Google. the keys is in the API keys section below

[image]

I think there are 3 keys that I just delete. Android, iOS and Web. I thought that I no longer need that key since I can create my own API keys. because I delete those 3 keys, now I can't get data from my Firestore in my mobile app, and I can't login using Firebase Auth.

what should I do?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because customer support is off-topic

Answer (score 6):

I get it. I manually create the API key then store it to the mobile app

1. go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
2. then click 'create credentials', choose API key, you can create two separate keys for Android and iOS, restrict it as you need.
3. copy the API key, something like AIzaSyC1wbl4AnYAzDW8
4. in your Android app. open google-services.json file, and then paste that API key you just create in "client" (choose the right client in the array, see the package name) --> "api_key" --> "current_key" . clean and rebuild your project, invalidate cache and restart. ( if you are using Flutter, then execute 'flutter clean' )
5. in your iOS app. open GoogleService-info.plist file, and then paste that API key you just create in the API_KEY